# I observe using `dd if=filein of=fileout` lead to filesystem fragmentation, what do I have to change?

Tags: filesystems, dd, defragmentation

There was a nice question that sadly got deleted while I was writing a rather extensive answer :(

Not wanting to let that effort go to waste, let me paraphrase that question from the question text and comments:

> I observe that using `dd` to overwrite files does increase fragmentation. I'm looking for an alternative to `dd` that doesn't lead to fragmentation.
>
> As an example for how that fragmentation happens: imagine a file which occupies the entire filesystem. Start overwriting it, you'll immediately see how the partition becomes completely "free", and you'll be able to write another file to it in the meantime. Blocks are allocated dynamically and there's zero guarantee older blocks will be reused when the file gets overwritten.
>
> I observe this behaviour on multiple file systems (ext2, 3 and 4, XFS, as well as FAT32 and NTFS) and on multiple OSes (win95 through modern Fedora)².
>
> I'm convinced this is independent of FS and OS.
>
> My main file system is a Bog standard ext4. FedoraROOT: 103874/1310720 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 1754833/5242880 blocks. Minimum overall fragmentation.

---

<sup>note that *I* myself cannot observe this, I'm trusting the original asker on these fragmentation claims!</sup>

Comment: Fragmentation is completely normal and can't be avoided in some cases. For example if the filesystem has distributed metadata (like backup superblocks), it will get in the way of large files at some point. So you might get fragmentation even if your filesystem is dedicated to a single file only. And normally *no one cares* because a few fragments don't affect performance, problems start when you have lots and lots of them. So if you need an unfragmented file for a special use-case you can't just toss a coin and hope for the best - you have to verify.

Comment: +1 for reposting this interesting question. However, as far as I had been able so read the question, (OP only since had not time to read comments) I had understood that its author was **not complaining against dd** because of fragmentation issues but because of performance issues. (using cache, reading one block, then writing it…) as well as inconveniencies in copying several files.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR! What's the tool I should use instead of `dd`?**: It's `cp`, if your GNU coreutils is recent enough.

## Actual file systems to the rescue

This is not FS-independent and OS-independent, at all! Allocation of blocks to files is a specific of specific file systems, in which they differ. So, it *cannot* strictly be independent!

### Ext4's delayed allocation to the rescue

Ext4 supports *allocate-on-flush*: Blocks are allocated to files as the data is flushed to disk, not earlier. This means that if your system (and a modern Fedora most definitely does that) uses file system buffers, the allocation sizes of files that are being sequentially extended are very large, so the fragmentation would be very low. You can activate that, and have to do nothing afterwards, but simply use `cp` or `dd` (I'd prefer `cp`, as that not only solves your first, but also your second question!).

In ext4, that's called *delayed allocation*; just add the `delalloc` mount option! (See `man ext4`)

Using `cp` will (on a modern Fedora) use a `copy_file_range` call, which then leads to a contiguous allocation when things are flushed to disk.

### XFS to the rescue

#### XFS does delayed allocation by default; see ext4.

#### same file system: `reflink`

When you use `cp` from Fedora >=34, or a GNU coreutils >=9.0 `cp`, it has support for `reflinks`, i.e. simply *not* copying data, but instead simply marking blocks as used by two files, and making only a copy if one changes. That's pretty nice feature, but of course only works if the source and target file are on the same file system.

The effect is that the target file is exactly as (un-)fragmented as the source file, because it is literally the same blocks.

#### different file system: XFS allocation groups

XFS doesn't manage the free and used space as "one thing" for the whole file system, it has multiple [*allocation groups*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocation_group). To cite `man xfs`:

> The data section contains all the filesystem metadata (inodes, directories, indirect blocks) as well as the user file data for  ordinary (non-realtime) files and the log area if the log is internal to the data section.  The data section is divided into a
> number of allocation groups.  The number and size of the  allocation
> groups are chosen by mkfs.xfs(8) so that there is  normally a small
> number of equal-sized groups.  The number of    allocation groups
> controls the amount of parallelism available in    file and block
> allocation.  It should be increased from the    default if there is
> sufficient memory and a lot of allocation    activity.  The number of
> allocation groups should not be set very    high, since this can cause
> large amounts of CPU time to be used    by the filesystem, especially
> when the filesystem is nearly full.    More allocation groups are
> added (of the original size) when    xfs_growfs(8) is run.

So, to solve the "concurrent allocation leads to fragmentation" problem, you simply need enough allocation groups! I'd expect a reasonably sized file system to have a couple, but simply increasing the count from the default (I use 5 for a 4-device striped LVM volume, so that seems to perform well) would work. You'd need to reformat or add more storage, however, to be able to increase the number of allocations groups.

## Tools to the rescue

`dd` isn't the tool of choice for overwriting a file with another: `cp` is; it will, in its current version (9.0) and the version shipped with your Fedora (8.32 with fedora patches) use `copy_file_range`, which tells the underlying file system how much data will be copied in the end – so that allocation simply works on block.

Comment: if `cp` doesn't use `copy_file_range()`, it'll likely just `open()` the target file with `O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`, which plausibly could result in the previously allocated blocks being freed and new allocations made. (That's what e.g. cp from coreutils 8.32 on Ubuntu 22.04 did when I tried it, and I read that as being the original issue.) Something like `cat srcfile 1<> dstfile && truncate -r srcfile dstfile` might do to actually overwrite the file and truncate it to length afterward.

Comment: @ilkkachu I checked that! It indeed does `openat(AT_FDCWD, "targetfile", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0644) = 4`, says [my strace](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/77bc150ef4c53ad6702006c9335a4b63#file-log2-strace-L276), and then does a bunch of `read()/write()`. Your `cat … 1<> …` is elegant, as it might lead to a `splice`

Comment: yes, that makes the suggestion to "just use `cp`" rather less than helpful.

Comment: well, I didn't say "just use `cp`", I said "cp in its current version and the version shipped with your fedora", aimed at the question that actually says "Fedora root file system"! But I didn't do that in the TL;DR, so I need to fix that.

Comment: @terdon thanks for the edit, you're right, this should stand on its own.